# varnishncsa does not show any output

Tags: linux, redhat, varnish, rhel6, varnishncsa

I have varnsih setup on my RHEL6.x. While the varnish, varnishlog and varnishstats show proper data varnisncsa does not log any data even  when run without any options defined. I have lsofed all the process and ensured that they are reading the proper _.vsm file. what could be happening that is causing varnishncsa to give out a blank output?

My /etc/sysconfig/varnishncsa file is as follows

```
#NCSA log format, to be used by HTTP log analyzers
VARNISHNCSA_ENABLED=yes
# Include log entries which result from communication with a backend server.
LOG_BACKEND=no
# Include log entries which result from communication with a client.
LOG_CLIENT=yes
#extra options to varnishncsa
DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS -F '%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"'"
```

Comment: have you checked for AVC denials (if SELinux is in enforcing mode)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Varnish as "transparent proxy" with "*return(pipe)*"?

In that case if you are using *return(pipe)* will have to change it to *return(pass)*.

From https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/tutorial/vcl.html

> **pass**
>
> When you return pass the request and subsequent response will be passed to and from the backend server. It will not be cached. pass can
>   be returned from vcl_recv
>
> **pipe**
>
> Pipe can be returned from vcl_recv as well. **Pipe short circuits the client and the
>   backend connections and Varnish will just sit there
>   and shuffle bytes back and forth. Varnish will not look at the data
>   being send back and forth - so your logs will be incomplete**. Beware
>   That with HTTP 1.1 client can send several requests on the same
>   connection and so You should instruct Varnish to add a "Connection:
>   close" header pipe before actually returning.